# An unrecoverable error occurred during installation. Component: 'Virtual Machine Platform' Error Code: 0x800700c1

Tags: linux, ubuntu

i want to insall ubuntu in my windows to use it's terminal i find this massage {An unrecoverable error occurred during installation. Component: 'Virtual Machine Platform' Error Code: 0x800700c1 }
and when i opend  "turn windows feature on or of " to enable  "windows Subsystems for linux " i get this massage too[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnn7P.png)
what should i do ??

i want to find the solution for this proplem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your computer supports Hardware Virtualization and then turn on Hardware Virtualization and VT-d in BIOS and save the settings.

Your second point and screen shot points to Hardware Virtualization not being enabled.

If standard settings do not work, Try spinning up a new virtual machine and see if that works.   That will help nail down the cause.

Comment: It points to it being disabled when it should be enabled

Comment: I have enabled all virtualization support from bios and the problem is still found !!

Comment: Try spinning up a new virtual machine and see if that works.